# QT: resizing a UI element with the mouse

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, resize

Is there the possibility to enable the built-in resize capability from the Qt designer in my program ?

I've a Qt UI element with implementation, which I added to a `QGraphicsView`.
Now I want to resize it like in my UI-Editor.
How can I enable this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QSizeGrip` in a layout inside your widget. This is a little hackis but is simple to implement :

```
myWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);

QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(myWidget);

QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout(myWidget);
layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);
```

The `QSizeGrip` class provides a resize handle for resizing top-level windows. When you set the widget flag `Qt::SubWindow`, then the user can resize it using the size grip.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use [QSplitters](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html). It is a method to organize graphic elements in a layout with a drag-able zone in between.

The use of splitters are explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9Zx_FJBC1U&t=4m20s), also have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671001/how-to-using-mouse-to-change-size-of-grid-layout-cells-using-qt).