# How to using mouse to change size of grid layout cells using Qt?

Tags: qt, layout, mouse, grid-layout

I use grid layout (horizontal and vertical too). I like the fact that when resizing the window fills the entire window contents. but this extension is poorly managed. I often want to change the size of only one column in grid layout without changing the size of the window. such as in Windows Explorer. there are two columns - the left list of directories and their contents to the left to the right. and i can always press mouse button therebetween and pulling change the mutual sizes of columns in relation to each other.

how can I do this in Qt?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a [QSplitter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html) rather than a [QGridLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html) in this specific case (where you just want 2 widgets shown together). QSplitters are draggable.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [**`QSplitter`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html#details)

(The following is the procedure in the Qt Designer)

1. Group your widgets, and click `Lay Out Horizontally/Vertically in Splitter`

[image]

2. Put this group into another layout (`QGridLayout`, for example) to automatically expand it.
3. Congrats! Your Layout is now draggable(from step1) and expandable(from step2).

Comment: thank you. its worked. I did not understand at first why this option was not enabled. it proved necessary to do before are grouped in grid layot